# Conditional expression for multiple form controls is not working in @rxweb/reactive-form-validators@2.1.2

Tags: angular, angular10

I have this form

```
this.customerDetailsFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            customer: [this.order.customer_details.name, [RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => !this.isNewCustomer })]],
            customer_details: this._formBuilder.group({
                name: [this.order.customer_details.name, [RxwebValidators.required({
                    conditionalExpression: (x, y) => {
                        console.log('name', this.isNewCustomer);
                        return this.isNewCustomer;
                    }
                }), RxwebValidators.maxLength({ value: 80 })]],
                company: [this.order.customer_details.company, [RxwebValidators.maxLength({ value: 100 })]],
                email: [this.order.customer_details.email, [RxwebValidators.required({
                    conditionalExpression: (x, y) => {
                        console.log('email', this.isNewCustomer);
                        return this.isNewCustomer;
                    }
                }), RxwebValidators.maxLength({ value: 255 }), RxwebValidators.email()]],
                mobile: [this.order.customer_details.mobile, [RxwebValidators.required({
                    conditionalExpression: (x, y) => {
                        return this.isNewCustomer;
                    }
                }), RxwebValidators.minLength({ value: 10 }), RxwebValidators.maxLength({ value: 10 })]],
            })
        });
```

In this form, I have a variable in condition expression **isNewCustomer** which is a boolean value based on which I am checking that if the fields should be required or not.

When the isNewCustomer variable value is true on **name** FormControl in **customer_details** FormGroup is getting validated not email and mobile.

I tried logging inside the conditionalExpression of email but it's not working. It seems like it is not working for multiple conditionalExpressions.

## Expected Behavior

All the FormControls having the conditionalExpression should get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, there was an issue in the package, now it has been fixed in the latest [release](https://github.com/rxweb/rxweb/issues/505).

please update the package.